# Update container height dynamically using css

Tags: css

I would like to implement a layout which consists of 3 cells;

A fixed header (position: fixed;),

B left menu,

C main container.

A and B with a fixed height.

C filling up the remaining space (just the remaining height).
Using CSS, how can I achieve this result?

The problem does occurs only when the C section height is less then the body/window height.

To the following [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hqCcx/5/)  you can get an example how to achieve this result. But it works only if you have one column.

http://jsfiddle.net/hqCcx/3/

[image]

Comment: What gap? Do you want it to fill the height of the page? What do you want it to do if the content of C would cause the page to scroll?

Comment: By the way, height: 100% doesn't really do anything in a modern browser. Height will always take up what it needs unless you specify a specific value like 600px, etc.

Comment: I'd like C section filling up the window size. If C cell causes the page to scroll there is no problem, because the empty space will be fill up from C. The problem is just when the height of C is less the window size!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally I found the solution...

The trick is to set the height of the outermost elements to be 100%

And than, the general rule to make 100% height is to set min-height on the content’s container.

```
html, body {height: 100%}

#content {min-height: 100%}
```

To this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hqCcx/10/) the working example.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to resort to using JavaScript to resize 'C', as CSS doesn't fill the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest thing you'll get with *pure CSS* is `min-height` on the C object.  I say "closest" because not all browsers support this, and it won't always fill the vertical space exactly.  It will be an estimation, and if you put anything below the C object, it might not appear in the browser without scrolling if the window isn't tall enough to show the minimum height that you've set.

Also, `min-height` with a percentage value doesn't do anything, which is why you're not getting the result you want in your jsfiddle example.  You have to use a non-percentage value like 300px or something.  Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LAaK/) that shows it in practice.  Uncomment the extra `Test<br />` lines to see what happens when the content is taller than the minimum height.

The other alternative is to jump to JavaScript and dynamically set the height of C when the page loads, but that can get messy (with respect to a cross-browser solution).

Comment: To the following link http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html you can get an example how to achieve this result. But it works only if you have one column.